# Cartogram + choropleth map in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, cartogram

I've been using ggplot2 lately to create a bunch of choropleths.  I was wondering if it was possible to use ggplot2 to create a map similar to this (from [WorldMapper](http://www.worldmapper.org/textindex/text_index.html)):

[image]

It's a choropleth where the shapefile polygons are distorted to represent relative population counts.  I believe this is called a cartogram.  They do this with a bunch of other variables.  In the spirit of the [Choropleth R Challenge](http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2009/11/choropleth-map-r-challenge.html), does anyone know how to do this using R?

Comment: You vcould try [ScapeToad](http://scapetoad.choros.ch/) for cartograms outside of R environment.

Comment: Thanks for this; ScapeToad works great and serves my needs.  However, I will leave the question up in case there's a solution within R.

Comment: I started working on integrating d3-cartogram with rCharts.  What is the structure of your data?

Comment: Just stumbled across this. Apparently, no good option in R exists. There are two packages that implement cartograms (`Rcartogram` and `cart`), but haven't been updated in years and are apparently cumbersome to install, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31613119/installing-rcartogram-packages-error-message and https://github.com/ggobi/cranvas/issues/210

Answer (score 8):

The `cartogram` [package](https://github.com/sjewo/cartogram), available on CRAN, has the rubber sheet distortion-style cartogram you want.

Answer (score 1):

This might work:

You will need to pre-install FFTW. [`Rcartogram` and `getcartr` you will need `devtools`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31613119/installing-rcartogram-packages-error-message).

Not sure how to do it in `ggplot2`, but here is another option.

Here I am using a shapefile from [Thematic World Map](http://thematicmapping.org/downloads/world_borders.php), after you download and unzip, you will get a folder called `TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3`.

For the choropleth/cartogram, you would reshape first with the size, and shade with a feature:

```
library(rgdal)#needed for readOGR
library(sp) #needed for spplot
library(Rcartogram)
library(getcartr)
setwd("<your_directory_with_shapefile>") #to the file that has your shapefile and your information file (in this case, a csv named datR)
#read shapefile
#here i have a folder with a shapefile and a csv with columns as ISO (IS02 for convenience) country and value
worldR <- readOGR(dsn = getwd(), layer= "TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3") # If reading a shapefile, the data source name (dsn= argument) is the folder (directory) where the shapefile is, and the layer is the name of the shapefile (without the .shp extension)
#names(worldR) #note how here there are columns for ISO2 (which matches a column named 'iso' in datR and LAT\LON
#[1] "FIPS"      "ISO2"      "ISO3"      "UN"        "NAME"      "AREA"      "POP2005"   "REGION"    "SUBREGION" "LON"       "LAT"
proj4string(worldR)
datR <- read.csv("datR.csv") #this is a file that has one column called 'score' and one column called size':

   head(datR)
  #  iso size     score
  #1  AE  323 0.9819077
  #2  AR  262 0.9591067
  #3  AT 7481 0.9987313
  #4  AU 5425 0.9837414
  #5  BA   31 0.9871938
  #6  BB   99 0.9715991

  ##Merge SpatialPolygonsDataFrame with other info
  map_dat <- merge(worldR, datR, by.x="ISO2",by.y="iso")
  #remove coordinate reference system arguments
  proj4string(map_dat) <- CRS(as.character(NA)) # from here https://github.com/chrisbrunsdon/getcartr/issues/1
  world.carto <- quick.carto(map_dat, map_dat$size, blur = 0)
  #plot(world.carto) #cartogram without anything
  #spplot size, color
  my.palette = c("#ff0000", "#ff8000", "#ffff00", "#bfff00","#00ff00") #red, orange, yellow, light green, dark green
  spplot(world.carto, 'score', col.regions = my.palette, cuts = length(my.palette)-1,main="Choropleth of score and cartogram of size")
```

This should give you a plot similar to this one:

[image]

I did this in a haste, let me know if it works