# Invalid `.internal.selfref` warning, column not updated working with `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame`

Tags: r, data.table, r-sp, r-maptools

I'm trying to do some geospatial analysis in `R` which will involve adding attributes to `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame`s for coloring, etc. during plotting.

For organization, I'd like to add these attributes to my `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame`s through a merge & update, but I keep getting the "Invalid `.internal.selfref`" warning & the columns won't be added.

Poking around the [questions and answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdata.table%5D+invalid+.internal.selfref+is%3Aquestion), it seems to be related to the fact that the data for a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` object is stored in a `list`, but the answers there were no help for how to deal with this as they were generally dealing with user-defined `list`s instead of those coming out of a package like here.

Here's a simple example using a silly shapefile, say [U.S. States](https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/cbf/cbf_state.html) (you'll note I use the 500k resolution below):

```
library(maptools)

us.states<-readShapePoly("cb_2014_us_state_5m.shp")

setDT(us.states@data) #works fine
> class(us.states@data)
[1] "data.table" "data.frame"

us.states@data[,test:=1L]
```

> Warning message: In`` `[.data.table`(us.states@data, , `:=`(test, 1L)) `` :
>   Invalid `.internal.selfref` detected and fixed by taking a (shallow)
>   copy of the `data.table` so that `:=` can add this new column by
>   reference. At an earlier point, this `data.table` has been copied by `R`
>   (or been created manually using `structure()` or similar). Avoid `key<-`,
>   `names<-` and `attr<-` which in `R` currently (and oddly) may copy the whole
>   `data.table`. Use `set*` syntax instead to avoid copying: `?set`, `?setnames`
>   and `?setattr`. Also, in `R<=v3.0.2`, `list(DT1,DT2)` copied the entire `DT1`
>   and `DT2` (`R`'s `list()` used to copy named objects); please upgrade to
>   `R>v3.0.2` if that is biting. If this message doesn't help, please
>   report to datatable-help so the root cause can be fixed.

This sort of jives with what I've gathered from the other related answers, but I at least expected the data to be updated, but alas:

```
> names(us.states@data)
[1] "STATEFP"  "STATENS"  "AFFGEOID" "GEOID"    "STUSPS"   "NAME"  
    "LSAD"     "ALAND"    "AWATER"
```

Is there any way I can continue to use the comfortable `:=` update by reference syntax for working with a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` (or similar `.shp`-retrieved object)?

For now, I'm using updates by copying, which works, e.g.:

```
us.states@data<-copy(us.states@data)[,test:=1L]

> names(us.states@data)
 [1] "STATEFP"  "STATENS"  "AFFGEOID" "GEOID"    "STUSPS"   "NAME"     "LSAD"    
 [8] "ALAND"    "AWATER"   "test"
```

Comment: How about `us.states@data <- setDT(us.states@data)`? Not ideal, but to avoid the copy until fixed.. Please file a bug.. I don't recall implementing for S4 objects.

Comment: @Arun [done](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1310), thanks. I don't think I catch your drift with your suggested fix, though. Perhaps you meant `us.states@data<-setDT(us.states@data[,test:=1L])`, which does work (but `tracemem` changes)

Comment: No drifts. I tried to avoid using `copy()`. `setDT()` does its job, but the shallow copied result is not assigned back to the parent env correctly. Hence the use of `<-` explicitly. `tracemem()` isn't going to help much in R v3.1+ as you can't tell if it's shallow or deep copying.. Try this: `DF = data.frame(x=1:5, y=6:10); tracemem(DF); DF$z = 11:15.. It's all shallow copy, but still `tracemem` reports. My suggestion was for you to avoid *deep* copying (for the meanwhile).

Comment: @Arun something else I noticed related to this -- `keep.rownames` doesn't seem to be working (e.g. `setDT(us.states,keep.rownames=T)` doesn't do so). this is quite important because the plot order gets screwed up when I merge... I suppose it's the same underlying issue. Should I add it to the [FR](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1310)?

Comment: Like I mentioned already, `setDT()` should be doing all you ask for. It just isn't able to assign it back to the parent env. Using `debugonce(setDT)` and running through it line by line should be helpful.