# Population-weighted polygon distortion (cartograms)

Tags: r, gis, r-sp, r-maptools, cartogram

I'm trying to create a map in R that conveys both the shape of underlying geometry (i.e., the physical boundaries) *and* the relative importance of the object in terms of an associated value.

For concreteness, I'd like to focus on reproducing (a version of) the following map* (the *shapes*, not so much the *colors* since I can't find the polling data):

[image: A distorted map of the United States titled "2012 Electoral College Map", subtitled "The size of each state is distorted to emphasize its share of electoral votes". The states are colored red or blue according to whether that state voted for Mitt Romney or Barack Obama in 2012, respectively. The legend notes this, as well as the total electoral vote count (277 for Obama, 261 for Romney), and a note that 270 electoral votes are required to win.]

I also don't want to bother with getting Alaska and Hawaii to appear below the US instead of in their geodesically correct locations.

I'm only as far as getting the data merged with the weights, done for example as follows:

## 1. Get polygons

```
library(maptools)
library(data.table) #not strictly necessary but I prefer it
#US states downloaded (500k resolution) from:
#https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/cbf/cbf_state.html
us.states<-
  readShapePoly("~/Desktop/cb_2014_us_state_5m.shp")

setDT(us.states@data)

#for getting rid of territories, AK, HI
states<-sprintf("%02d",1:59)
ak.hi<-c("02","15")

us.states.contig<-
  us.states[us.states@data$STATEFP %in% 
              setdiff(states,ak.hi),]

#Unadorned plot
plot(us.states.contig)
text(coordinates(us.states.contig),
     us.states.contig@data[,paste0(STUSPS)],
     cex=.7)
```

[image: A plain, undistorted map of the continental United States. White polygons, black borders, annotated with two-letters state postal codes.]

## 2. Add Electoral College data

```
#scraped from government page
library(rvest) #only necessary to scrape table
electoral.college.url<-
  paste0("http://www.archives.gov/federal-register/",
         "electoral-college/allocation.html")

electoral.college.dt<-
  (html(electoral.college.url) %>%
     html_nodes("table"))[[5]] %>% 
  html_table()
setDT(electoral.college.dt)
setnames(electoral.college.dt,c("State","Votes"))

#merge into geodata
us.states.contig@data<-
  copy(us.states.contig@data)[
    electoral.college.dt,electoral.votes:=i.Votes,
    on=c(NAME="State")]

#plot, coloring each state by size
states.ranked<-
  us.states.contig@data[,rank(electoral.votes,
                              ties.method="first")]
cols<-colorRampPalette(c("red","blue"))(51)[states.ranked]

plot(us.states.contig,col=cols)
```

[image: The same undistorted map of states, but this time, each state is colored red, blue, or purple. Red means "few electoral college votes" (for example, North and South Dakota are starkly red); blue means "many electoral college votes" (for example, Texas and California are starkly blue); colors on the gradient in between are "medium electoral college votes"]

This is all well and good--with a glance at this map, we can tell which states have high & low representation in the electoral college. But what if (as in our target map) we wanted to represent another variable with the color of the state?

## 3. Add 2012 Elections outcomes

```
#scrape again
#2012 Election Results by State
election.wiki<-
  paste0("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/",
         "United_States_presidential_election,_2012")
         
results<-
  html(election.wiki) %>%
  html_node(xpath='//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div[22]/table') %>%
  html_table()
#eliminate second header row, delete final row,
#  keep only the important columns
results.trim<-results[2:(nrow(results)-1),c(1,4,21)]
colnames(results.trim)<-c("name","pct","abbr")
results.dt<-setDT(results.trim)
#data idiosyncrasies, see Wiki page
results.dt<-results.dt[!grepl("–",abbr)|grepl("a",abbr)]
results.dt[grepl("–",abbr),abbr:=gsub("–.*","",abbr)]
results.dt[,"pct":=as.numeric(gsub("%","",pct))]

#merge
us.states.contig@data<-
  copy(us.states.contig@data
       )[results.dt,vote.pct:=i.pct,
         on=c(STUSPS="abbr")]
                              
pcts<-us.states.contig@data[,vote.pct]
cols<-c("red","blue")[(pcts>=50)+1L]
tx.col<-c("white","black")[(cols=="red")+1L]
plot(us.states.contig,col=cols)
text(coordinates(us.states.contig),
     us.states.contig@data[,paste0(STUSPS)],
     col=tx.col)
```

[image: The undistorted states again, this time exactly red or blue according to the electoral outcome.]

This last graph gets at the crux of the issue. The first graph presented is far superior in the sense that we can sense from the percentage red vs. blue of the map whether the Republicans or Democrats won; this last map is misleading because the most Republican states are also the most sparsely-populated.

Is there any way to create a distorted version of this map which conveys the relative importance of each state in the electoral college? I couldn't find any help online, perhaps mainly because I don't know if there's a standard name for this type of graph.

*This map was found [here](http://www.fweil.com/Elections/2012/Election2012.html); I've seen similar size-distorted maps before, e.g. in [The Economist](http://cdn.static-economist.com/sites/default/files/2015328_woc001_0.png?1427218970). It appears it's based on the work of [Dr. Sam Wang at Princeton's Election Consortium](http://election.princeton.edu/) and was produced by [Drew Thaler](http://drewthaler.blogspot.com/).

Comment: The distorted maps are usually called "cartograms". I'm tempted to mark as duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9319597/903061). There's an R package that does it directly (not on CRAN, it's linked in an answer but looks to be pretty woefully out-of-date), but [this blog entry](http://spatial.ly/2013/06/r_activity/) suggests that using [scape toad](http://scapetoad.choros.ch/) via R is more powerful.

Comment: @Gregor I agree it seems like a duplicate, but as you pointed out perhaps it could go for an update with the functions you suggested. thanks for your help with the vocab. I'll read these over & either post as an answer to this or the other question using scape toad.

Comment: Yeah, it is a duplicate but given the age of the answers available leaves a lot of room for improvement,

Comment: @Gregor The [blog entry you mention](http://spatial.ly/2013/06/r_activity/) does indeed say that ScapeToad is more powerful software than the [RCartogram package](http://www.omegahat.org/Rcartogram/). I would be interested to know in what sense ScapeToad is more powerful. The algorithm used in ScapeToad is the one from Mark Newman and Michael Gastner, and the code is very similar to a large extent (the initial C code is [here](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~mejn/cart/) and the paper for the algorithm is [here](http://www.pnas.org/content/101/20/7499.abstract).

Comment: @chkaiser compared to ScapeToad, I would consider `Rcartogram` to be nebulous / poorly documented / experts-only, in other words the learning curve for using `Rcartogram` is quite steep. The answer to the [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9319597/cartogram-choropleth-map-in-r) linked here trivializes this and we can find [other instances](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18419617/use-rcartogram-on-a-spatialpolygonsdataframe-object) of users struggling to wrap their heads around how to use the package.

Comment: @MichealChirico Very interesting and helpful points. We should probably improve documentation on Rcartogram. There is also a [command-line implementation of ScapeToad by Luca Palli](https://github.com/lpalli/ScapeToad) (a fork of [my repo](https://github.com/christiankaiser/ScapeToad)) which might help (though I haven't tried it out yet). I consider merging it with my ScapeToad repo anytime soon, or implementing similar functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the advice of package maintainer @chkaiser, I've sought out and finally discovered a way to do this within R. [This blog post](http://vietletruc.com/cartogram-plotting-using-r/) was a tremendous help and the `getcartr` package is fantastic.

First, get the `Rcartogram` and `getcartr` packages from GitHub:

```
remotes::install_github("omegahat/Rcartogram")
remotes::install_github('chrisbrunsdon/getcartr', subdir='getcartr')
library(Rcartogram)
library(getcartr)
```

Now simply plug & chug:

```
us.states.contig.carto = quick.carto(
  us.states.contig,
  us.states.contig@data$electoral.votes
)
plot(us.states.contig.carto, col = cols)
text(
  coordinates(us.states.contig.carto),
  us.states.contig@data[ , paste0(STUSPS)],
  col = tx.col
)
```

And just like that we have our cartogram:

[image: cartogram]