# R 3.3.0 installing a package on Windows: gcc not found error

Tags: r, gcc, package

I am trying to install an R package which contains some C code under Windows. I have R 3.3.0 installed and also Rtools 3.3.0 installed on my computer's D: disk.

And `d:\Rtools\bin` and `d:\Rtools\mingw_64\bin` are all in PATH. I checked gcc command under command window, and it is working.

But when I am installing the package, it always trying to use `c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/gcc`, which should be in `d:` disk, then it gives `c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/gcc: not found` error.

Can anyone help on this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try it with `devtools` and/or RStudio? Perhaps you can try it with this example, if your PATH is right: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19885381/rtools-not-being-detected-by-r

Comment: Actually, this only happens to R 3.3.0, for other version of R, e.g.3.2.3, they can automatically find the right path of gcc, as long as it is in PATH. So I am not sure whether this is a bug of R 3.3.0.

Answer (score 21):

OK, I sent an email to the R-package-devel group regarding to this issue. And the following is the reply, and it does work!

> `Please adapt your BINPREF variable in R/etc/$Arch/Makeconf files 
>   appropriately to point to the coresponding compiler for each 
>   architecture - this is new with the new toolchain we use with R >= 3.3.0.`

Comment: Did they tell you as well why this was introduced and why at this place? In my case I cannot alter this file as I do not have admin privileges. That is a rather stupid feature...

Comment: Please also not that paths need to be given as DOS paths, i.e. instead of `C:\Program Files` one needs to use `C:\PROGRA~1` and instead of `C:\Program Files (x86)` one needs to use `C:\PROGRA~2`.

Comment: For details on how to set the BINPREF variable see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/44035904/4468078

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to edit the Makefile directly (as of R 3.6.3 at least), you can set `BINPREF` as an environment variable pointing to the appropiate `mingw_{32,64}/bin/` path

Couple of gotcha's on Windows to note:

- Need to use forward slahes in the path (and so can't use any
  environment variables like `%LocalAppData%` in there)
- Trailing forward
  slash after `bin`