# How to install RTools without admin privileges on Windows

Tags: r

To build my package, I need to install RTools on my Windows computer at work, where I don't have admin privileges.

As the installer is a .exe file, I cannot even open it (blocked by Bromium vSentry). So I cannot choose an installation folder where I have write privileges, as I cannot even launch the installer.

I Googled it but could not find a portable version of RTools or a zip I could just uncompress. Does anyone know if it exists and if not, what is the way to build my packages?

**Edit:**

As a complement to Hong Ooi's answer, I indeed had to update my PATH variable manually for RStudio to find RTools. The PATH to set is not documented anywhere official, so I copied and adapted the PATH from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19885381/rtools-not-being-detected-by-r). My version is:

```
C:\Unsupported\Rtools\bin;C:\Unsupported\Rtools\gcc-4.6.3\bin;C:\Unsupported\Rtools\perl\bin;C:\Unsupported\Rtools\MinGW\bin;C:\Unsupported\R\R-3.3.2\bin\x64;C:\Unsupported\R\R-3.3.2\bin
```

Comment: I thought you could install it to a location you do have permission.  You just won't be able to install it in the default `C` drive.  You will just need to update your `PATH` accordingly to point to wherever it is installed.

Comment: It's a .exe file, so I'm not even allowed to launch it, as it comes from an "untrusted" place. What I'm looking for is a zip file I could uncompress.

Comment: Maybe there is a way to compile RTools from source? Maybe it's even more complicated...

Comment: Since you've put RTools in a different location to the default, you may also want to look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37729082/r-3-3-0-installing-a-package-on-windows-gcc-not-found-error) if you're using R 3.3.

Comment: @Ben Could you Elaborate a bit more how you manually set the path? I copied an RTools Folder from my own PC, but I am stuck on what to do now.

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/813298

Comment: Thanks, but I do not have enough rights to set a new System variable, let alone open the adminstration panel. using `set`  in the `cmd` I could not find a ZIP variable, so I am probably doomed. Did you have to set new System variable? Could you add the exact code you use in R to set the zip variable?

Comment: The solution provided by @MaxM works for me. I changed the system path by using the Sys.setenv(PATH = "/path/") command in R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could install RTools on your own PC, then zip up the directory it creates (`c:\Rtools` by default), copy to a USB stick and unzip it on your work PC. Although if your company blocks untrusted exes, I suspect it'll also block USB ports....

Comment: They don't block USB ports, so that should work, thanks. I was hoping someone already did that operation and that the zip file would have been available on the net.

Comment: The installer does more than just put the files on your hard disk; it also sets some entries in the registry and updates your path. But you should be able to get by without these.

Answer (score 0):

I have this same problem too.  What worked for me was to find a place on my computer I have read/write access.  For me this was on my local C: drive that wasn't connected to network for backups.

When you install R, you need to direct it to install all packages in that same directly you have permission.  In R you can do this with `.libPaths()`.  The path for RTools needs to follow same procedure.  This worked for me.  I installed Rstudio the same way.

Comment: The problem is that the security software won't let him run the installer in the first place.

Comment: I see. So this solution won't work... although it may be helpful for others so I'll leave it for now.

Comment: How do you use `.libPaths()` to tell R where is the RTools folder for non-default locations?