# Problem in installing dependency"digest" for RStudio

Tags: r, hash

I was trying to install tidyverse, but many other packages such as forecast, and I keep having the same problem related to the dependency 'digest'.

From when I encounter the error onwards, all other packages do not install correctly.

The main problem seems to be here **gcc: error: aes.o: No such file or directory**, but I do not understand what this aes.o is.

```
if(!require("tidyverse"))install.packages("tidyverse")
Loading required package: tidyverse
there is no package called ‘tidyverse’Installing package into ‘/home/LU/fmarchioro001/R/MRO/3.4.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependencies ‘htmltools’, ‘digest’, ‘knitr’, ‘rmarkdown’, ‘ggplot2’, ‘reprex’

  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 45408  100 45408    0     0  36462      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:-- 36472
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  118k  100  118k    0     0  84112      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:-- 84168
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  634k  100  634k    0     0   142k      0  0:00:04  0:00:04 --:--:--  150k
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 2044k  100 2044k    0     0   246k      0  0:00:08  0:00:08 --:--:--  289k
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 2161k  100 2161k    0     0   369k      0  0:00:05  0:00:05 --:--:--  458k
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 22776  100 22776    0     0  20019      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:-- 20031
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 61647  100 61647    0     0  49020      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:-- 49042
* installing *source* package ‘digest’ ...
** package ‘digest’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/opt/microsoft/rclient/3.4.3/runtime/R/include -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION   -fpic  -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -g -O2  -c aes.c -o aes.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/opt/microsoft/rclient/3.4.3/runtime/R/include -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION   -fpic  -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -g -O2  -c crc32.c -o crc32.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/opt/microsoft/rclient/3.4.3/runtime/R/include -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION   -fpic  -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -g -O2  -c digest.c -o digest.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/opt/microsoft/rclient/3.4.3/runtime/R/include -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION   -fpic  -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -g -O2  -c init.c -o init.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/opt/microsoft/rclient/3.4.3/runtime/R/include -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION   -fpic  -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -g -O2  -c md5.c -o md5.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/opt/microsoft/rclient/3.4.3/runtime/R/include -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION   -fpic  -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -g -O2  -c pmurhash.c -o pmurhash.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/opt/microsoft/rclient/3.4.3/runtime/R/include -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION   -fpic  -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -g -O2  -c raes.c -o raes.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/opt/microsoft/rclient/3.4.3/runtime/R/include -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION   -fpic  -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -g -O2  -c sha1.c -o sha1.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/opt/microsoft/rclient/3.4.3/runtime/R/include -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION   -fpic  -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -g -O2  -c sha2.c -o sha2.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/opt/microsoft/rclient/3.4.3/runtime/R/include -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION   -fpic  -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -g -O2  -c sha256.c -o sha256.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/opt/microsoft/rclient/3.4.3/runtime/R/include -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION   -fpic  -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -g -O2  -c xxhash.c -o xxhash.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -shared -L/usr/local/lib64 -o digest.so aes.o crc32.o digest.o init.o md5.o pmurhash.o raes.o sha1.o sha2.o sha256.o xxhash.o
**gcc: error: aes.o: No such file or directory
make: *** [digest.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘digest’
* removing ‘/home/LU/fmarchioro001/R/MRO/3.4.3/digest’
Warning in install.packages/opt/microsoft/rclient/3.4.3/runtime/R/share/make/shlib.mk:6: recipe for target 'digest.so' failed**
 :
  installation of package ‘digest’ had non-zero exit status
```

Also, I am using R version 3.4.3 on an online platform. Might it be a compatibility problem?

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /opt/microsoft/rclient/3.4.3/runtime/R/lib/libRblas.so
LAPACK: /opt/microsoft/rclient/3.4.3/runtime/R/lib/libRlapack.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] RevoUtilsMath_10.0.1 RevoUtils_10.0.7     RevoMods_11.0.0      MicrosoftML_9.3.0    RevoScaleR_9.3.0     lattice_0.20-35      rpart_4.1-11        

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] compiler_3.4.3         R6_2.2.2               tools_3.4.3            CompatibilityAPI_1.1.0 codetools_0.2-15       grid_3.4.3             mrupdate_1.0.1        
 [8] iterators_1.0.9        foreach_1.4.5          jsonlite_1.5
```

Thanks

Comment: I suggest trying @Ashish solution, eventually using `remotes::install_cran("digest")` (after installing the `remotes` package). Then you can check for a RTools issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19885381/rtools-not-being-detected-by-r) or try to fix the path [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37729082/r-3-3-0-installing-a-package-on-windows-gcc-not-found-error)

Comment: I tried installing digest  manually and I still have the same error. Also, after installing remotes i get this error `remotes::install_cran("digest")
Error: 'install_cran' is not an exported object from 'namespace:remotes'`

Comment: I rechecked `remotes::install_cran()` and it should be correct. You should explore the other options mentioned above. I see you are using R 3.4.3, you may also consider using the last version of R (3.6.2).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried manually installing the "digest" package?

```
install.packages("digest")
```

Install the digest package and try again because I had a similar issue and it was resolved when I manually installed the "digest" package.