# Rcpp Rtools installed but error message g++ not found

Tags: c++, g++, environment-variables, rcpp

I have consulted existing entries on SO related to my specific issue, but still could not resolve it.

I am trying to do this with my machine at work, where I have limited admin rights, but I can run Rtools.exe, so I installed it.

My setup for R is:

```
 platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
 arch           x86_64                      
 os             mingw32                     
 system         x86_64, mingw32             
 version.string R version 3.3.0 (2016-05-03)
```

I am RStudion Version 0.99.902. I installed Rtools version 3.3.0.1959.

All of R, Rstudio, and Rtools are installed in C:/WORK/, which is where I have some limited admin rights.

In my system ENV variable, I have set up:

```
 C:\\WORK\\Rtools\\bin; C:\\WORK\\Rtools\\gcc-  4.6.3\\bin; C:\\WORK\\R-3.3.0\\bin\\x64;"
```

When I run

```
 system('where make')
```

I get

```
 C:\WORK\Rtools\bin\make.exe
```

When I run

```
 system('g++ -v')
```

I get:

```
 Using built-in specs.
 COLLECT_GCC=C:\WORK\Rtools\GCC-46~1.3\bin\G__~1.EXE
 COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=c:/WORK/rtools/gcc-46~1.3/bin/../libexec/gcc/i686-w64-   mingw32/4.6.3/lto-wrapper.exe
 Target: i686-w64-mingw32
 Configured with: /data/gannet/ripley/Sources/mingw-test3/src/gcc/configure --host=i686-w64-mingw32 --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=i686-w64-mingw32 --with-sysroot=/data/gannet/ripley/Sources/mingw-test3/mingw32mingw32/mingw32 --prefix=/data/gannet/ripley/Sources/mingw-test3/mingw32mingw32/mingw32 --with-gmp=/data/gannet/ripley/Sources/mingw-test3/mingw32mingw32/prereq_install --with-mpfr=/data/gannet/ripley/Sources/mingw-test3/mingw32mingw32/prereq_install --with-mpc=/data/gannet/ripley/Sources/mingw-test3/mingw32mingw32/prereq_install --disable-shared --enable-static --enable-targets=all --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran --enable-libgomp --enable-sjlj-exceptions --enable-fully-dynamic-string --disable-nls --disable-werror --enable-checking=release --disable-win32-registry --disable-rpath --disable-werror CFLAGS='-O2 -mtune=core2 -fomit-frame-pointer' LDFLAGS=
 Thread model: win32
 gcc version 4.6.3 20111208 (prerelease) (GCC)
```

When I compile, I get this error:

```
 Error in compileCode(f, code, language = language, verbose = verbose) : 
 Compilation ERROR, function(s)/method(s) not created!
 c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/g++: not found
```

My question is: why is R still looking for g++ in

```
 c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/g++
```

Didn't I already set R to look for it in

```
 C:/WORK/Rtools?
```

Even when I manually added

```
 c:/WORK/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/g++
```

in the ENV variable, I still got the same error. (I cannot make Rtools folder in C:/ due to admin rights.)

Has anyone run into this specific issue?

Comment: Sys.getenv()['PATH'] gives `C:\WORK\R-3.3.0\bin\x64; C:\WORK\Rtools\bin; C:\WORK\Rtools\mingw_64\bin; C:\WORK\Rtools\bin; C:\WORK\Rtools\mingw_32\bin; C:\WORK\R-3.3.0\bin\x64; C:\WINDOWS\system32; C:\WINDOWS; C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem; C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14; C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;     Sys.getenv()['PATH']                                   C:\APPS\Global\dev_tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Enterprise Vault\EVClient\; C:\WORK\TortoiseSVN\bin; C:\WORK\Rtools\bin; C:\WORK\Rtools\mingw_64\bin; C:\WORK\R-3.3.0\bin\x64`

Answer (score 24):

The path `c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/` is hard-coded into the file `Makeconf`located somewhere in the R installation (in my case `C:\Progs\R\R-3.4.1\etc\x64`), as the value of the variable BINPREF.

The easiest thing to do is to change this path to your path `C:/WORK/Rtools/bin` (in my case was `C:/Progs/RTools/3.4/mingw_64/bin/`). That worked for me in a fresh installation of R-3.4.1 and Rtools3.4, and a minimal example.

Comment: Modifying `Makeconf` file should be included as a step in updating Rtools

Comment: Especially since it is installed in `RBuildTools` directory by default. Thank you!

Comment: Might be worth noting that if you can't edit `Makeconf`, you can override `BINPREF` using a `Makevars` file in your home directory.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/56525698/1714

Answer (score 4):

What is happening is the need to be on RTools 34 and **NOT** 33 for R 3.3.x.

Remove the rtools install and then follow the guide here:

http://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/rcpp/install-rtools-for-rcpp/

@David, you need to remove all instances of `C:\WORK\Rtools\<something>` and any duplicates (e.g. `C:\WORK\R-3.3.0\bin\x64` appears twice.) Then add:

> c:\WORK\Rtools\bin;
>   c:\WORK\Rtools\mingw_32\bin;

Comment: The page at https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/ mentions Rtools3.3 to R 3.2.* and R 3.3.*, and Rtools3.4 for R 3.3.* and up, implying a choice.  So OP may just have a `PATH` issue?

Comment: I uninstalled Rtools33 and installed Rtools34. I still got the same error message:    "Compilation ERROR, function(s)/method(s) not created! c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/g++: not found".                 I still can't get R to look for "Rtools/mingw_64/bin" in the place I installed even though I added the path in the ENV variable's PATH.

Comment: Please add the output from the following to your post above:

`Sys.getenv()['PATH']`

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel , I've had better luck on Windows builds associating R with the latest RTools. You are correct in this case that it is definitely a path issue.

Comment: I am with you that the newest is generally a safe bet; I simply wanted to state that Rtools3.4 was not the only game in town.  And yes, I too was bitten by the `PATH` just last week updating a vm.

Comment: C:\WORK\R-3.3.0\bin\x64;
 C:\WORK\Rtools\bin;
 C:\WORK\Rtools\mingw_64\bin;
 C:\WORK\Rtools\bin;
 C:\WORK\Rtools\mingw_32\bin;
 C:\WORK\R-3.3.0\bin\x64;
 C:\WINDOWS\system32;
 C:\WINDOWS;
 C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14;
 C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
 C:\APPS\Global\dev_tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Enterprise Vault\EVClient\;
 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office15\root\office15;
 C:\WORK\TortoiseSVN\bin;
 C:\WORK\Rtools\bin;
 C:\WORK\Rtools\mingw_64\bin;
 C:\WORK\R-3.3.0\bin\x64 (There are some repeats, I realize) Thx!

Comment: @David see above.

Comment: The newest version of Rtools actually constructs paths to the gcc / g++ compilers on demand; you now only need `Rtools\bin` on the `PATH`. When `make.exe` is called, R will then effectively tell it to look for `gcc` at `..\mingw_64\bin\gcc.exe` (assuming 64bit Windows). Note that the directories `Rtools\mingw_32` and `Rtools\mingw_64` should be populated by default by the new Rtools installers.

Comment: @KevinUshey Are you sure about this? Using the latest version of Rtools (version 3.4.0.1964), if I only put, e.g., `C:\R\devel34\Rtools\bin` (but not `C:\R\devel34\Rtools\mingw_64\bin`) on my `PATH`, running `Rcpp::evalCpp("2+2")` fails with a message that `c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/g++: not found`. (Of course, if I've also got another installation of Rtools with `C:\Rtools\mingw_64\bin\g++`, it works, and the failure to find `C:\R\Rdevel34\mingw_64\bin` is masked...)

Comment: Hmm. It actually works for me with the `PATH` left completely unset, so maybe R checks some default locations for Rtools? (I notice you don't have Rtools installed in the default location)

Comment: @KevinUshey Exactly. In other words, Rtools doesn't search for a `gcc.exe` in a path relative to the supplied `Rtools\bin`. Instead, it in effect appends the paths `C:\Rtools\bin` and `C:\Rtools\mingw_64\bin` to `PATH`, and will use the executables in those directories (if they exist) unless those executables are found early on along the search path. So as @coatless indicates, you'll need to add two directories to your `PATH` if you want to use an Rtools distribution installed elsewhere than the default location.

Answer (score 2):

I was hitting the same issue on Windows 10 with RStudio 1.3+ and RTools 4.0. After installing RTools and trying to install another package (that needed RTools) it kept throwing the error

> c:/rtools40/mingw32/bin/g++: No such file or directory

It kept picking up the wrong path of the RTools installation on windows. After restarting RStudio it picked up the right path:

> C:\RBuildTools\4.0\mingw32\bin

Comment: RStudio restart solved this for me as well

Answer (score 1):

A plausible and easy way to do this is to choose "Full installation to build 32 or 64 bit" in the following promp.[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved like this:  Just copy the files needed in the path where it is looking for.
( my case, in C:\rtools40\mingw64\ copied the bin directory into the path he search for and worked !)

Answer (score 0):

Some years later I have had a very similar problem on Windows 10, R 4.3.1. I'm documenting the details here for the next poor sod:

When installing from source I would get the error

```
* installing *source* package 'StanHeaders' ...
** package 'StanHeaders' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
using C compiler: 'gcc.exe (x86_64-posix-seh, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 4.9.3'
G__~1.EXE: error: unrecognized command line option '-std=gnu++17'
using C++ compiler: 'G__~1.EXE (x86_64-posix-seh, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 4.9.3'
using C++17
```

even after fully uninstalling and re-installing R and RStudio, rtools43, etc.

The Path lists in the Windows system and user environmental variables made no mention of mingw, somehow R had retained an internal path configuration in the Makeconf file between reinstallations despite the files being deleted. Even adding the correct directory to the Windows path variables did not change the behaviour.

As this thread suggested, I had to find the Makeconf file in `C:\Program Files\R\R-4.3.1\etc\x64` and modify the BINPREF variable manually. After setting BINPREF to

```
BINPREF = C:\RBuildTools\4.3\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin
```

(and specifically removing the ? before the =), I then needed to restart the computer completely and reinstall StanHeaders and rstan to force the change to be retained.

If you don't have the ability to open the Makeconf file in administrator mode you might not be able to make those changes.

[Rcpp Rtools installed but error message g++ not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39090983/rcpp-rtools-installed-but-error-message-g-not-found)