# Rcpp does not find Rtools

Tags: r, rcpp

**My Problem**

I installed `Rtools` and added the path to my `PATH` variable:

```
mPath <- strsplit(Sys.getenv("PATH"), ";")[[1]]
mPath[grep("Rtools", mPath)]
# [1] "C:\\Temp\\Rtools\\bin"              "C:\\Temp\\Rtools\\gcc-4.6.3\\bin"  
# [3] "C:\\Temp\\Rtools\\gcc-4.6.3\\bin32" "C:\\Temp\\Rtools\\mingw_32\\bin"
```

(So you can see it is not installed directly at `c:\Rtools`)

When I try to run a simple `Rcpp` snippet, I get the following error:

```
library(Rcpp)
evalCpp("1+1")
```

> [...]
>
> c:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++: not found

So basically `Rcpp` is looking in `C:/Rtools` ignoring my `PATH` variable.

**Workaround**

If I run

```
library(installr)
install.Rtools()
```

> Loading required namespace: devtools
>
> No need to install Rtools - You've got the relevant version of Rtools installed

and then run `evalRcpp("1+1")` again, everything works as expected.

**My Question**

Why does it not work right away? How do I tell `Rcpp` to look in the right folder? How does `install.Rtools` manage to convince `Rcpp` to look into the right folder? How can I achieve that without the workaround?

Comment: We have nothing to do with `install.Rtools()`; talk to its authors. We recommend to follow the instructions in [R Installation and Administration](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-admin.html), particularly the relevant appendices, and _to the letter_.  Also note IIRC  there was a regression a few R releases ago. You may now _have to_ install into `C:/Rtools`.

Comment: This is exactly the issue @DirkEddelbuettel. You _really_ cannot have a custom path with modifying the local `Makevars` file.

Comment: You used to in the path though.

Comment: The `PATH` variable is required. But, there is a hardcoded path for the binary that gets picked up as well. It's a long story. Remind me at the end of the week and I'll write up an addendum for the _Rtools_ post.

Comment: I have the same problem. Rcpp is looking in `C:/Rtools/3.4` even though I am using RTools35 and it's installed in `C:/Rtools/`, which is in `PATH` as required.

Comment: `WARNING: Rtools 3.5 found on the path at C:/Rtools is not compatible with R 3.5.1.`

Comment: try Makeconf file: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39090983/rcpp-rtools-installed-but-error-message-g-not-found

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. The system is not (yet) compatible with Rtools 3.5. Also, there seems to be an issue that they re-named it to RBuildTools instead of RTools. Install the former version 3.4 on https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/. This did the job for me!