# Failed installing OpenCV using RStudio

Tags: r, cmake

I tried installing OpenCV using Rstudio (R version 3.6.3). I installed both Rtools and CMake and added them to the PATH. I received following error:

```
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:106 (enable_language):
  The CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:

    c:/Rtools/mingw32/bin/g++.exe

  is not a full path to an existing compiler tool.
```

Please help.

Comment: It seems [g++](https://www.cs.bu.edu/fac/gkollios/cs113/Usingg++.html) is missing

Comment: Thanks.....so how should i solve the problem ?

Comment: Maybe try to see if something here works: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39090983/rcpp-rtools-installed-but-error-message-g-not-found