# R is using the mingw_32 to compile packages for 64-bit architecture

Tags: r, package

Periodically – I think whenever I update R – I have problems installing packages from source on my 64-bit Windows machine.

Today I'm trying to install a package using `devtools::install_github()`.  The installation proceeded fine on my laptop, but my not on my desktop, which can install the package under `*** arch - i386`, but under `*** arch - x64`, which reports  the error message

> C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.4/bin/x64/R.dll: file not recognized: File format not recognized

The command that caused the error is

`C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++ -shared -s -static-libgcc -o PACKAGENAME.dll [...]`

I believe that the error is arising because R is using mingw_32 to attempt to compile a 64-bit package.  The question is, where can I tell R to use mingw_64?  I've already checked all the places that I can recall:

- `R-3.4.4/etc/x64/Makeconf` states
  `BINPREF ?= c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/`
- My system `PATH` (verified from within R using `Sys.getenv('PATH')`) includes mingw_64 ahead of mingw_32.

R must be looking somewhere else to decide which compiler to use... but where?

Comment: do you want to install the 32bit library as well or do you just want to install the 64bit lib?

Comment: I'd prefer to have both the 32-bit and the 64-bit installed, but a solution that allows me to get up and running with just the 64-bit version would still be very useful!

Comment: ok maybe pass in `INSTALL_opts='--no-multiarch'` into `install_github`

Comment: `devtools::install_github(package, args='--no-multiarch')` seemed to do the trick, thanks – much appreciated.  It'd still be nice to know the solution to the underlying problem, though.

Comment: see also https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=16919 and also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33103203/rtools-is-not-being-detected-from-rstudio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Via [R CMD check not looking for gcc in Rtools directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47076620/r-cmd-check-not-looking-for-gcc-in-rtools-directory/47076968#47076968):

R was looking in `C:/Users/MYUSERNAME/Documents/.R/Makevars` for the value of `BINPREF`.  Deleting the contents of this file removed the incorrect location.

`$RPATH/etc/i386/Makeconf` is re-created with each new installation of R, and contains the line
`BINPREF ?= c:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/`.
The `?=` operator will set the value of `BINPREF` if it is not already set, as it was in the `Makevars` file mentioned above.  So replacing `?=` with `=` will work until a new version of R is installed and the `Makeconf` file is overwritten – updating, or uninstalling, R will not modify the `Makevars` file in the User directory.

Comment: This issue was driving me crazy after updating to rtools 4.0 and your suggestion fixed it. I believe that I populated the "Marevars" file when I complied rstan, and deleting those files cleaned it up.

Answer (score 0):

If you start digging from `devtools::install_github`, it will lead you through the following functions:

```
devtools::install_github
devtools:::install_remotes
devtools:::try_install_remote
devtools:::install_remote
devtools:::install
devtools:::check_build_tools
devtools:::setup_rtools
devtools:::scan_path_for_rtools
```

And when you run the following code:

```
devtools:::scan_path_for_rtools(TRUE)
devtools:::setup_rtools(debug=TRUE)
```

Most likely, it is saying that Rtools is not currently installed. (Yes, a bit counterintuitive given that you already have it installed in C:/Rtools but maybe not registered in registry)

To fix it, you will need to run (which is in essence the solution in [Rtools is not being detected from RStudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33103203/rtools-is-not-being-detected-from-rstudio/44035904#44035904))

```
Sys.setenv(PATH=paste0("C:\\Rtools\\bin;", Sys.getenv("PATH")))
devtools:::set_rtools_path(structure(list(path="c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin", version=3.4), class="rtools"))
devtools:::set_rtools_path(structure(list(path="c:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin", version=3.4), class="rtools"))
```

Please let me know if this works.

Comment: `scan_path_for_rtools` finds `Rtools version 3.4.0.1964`, and `setup_rtools` reports the same. `set_rtools_path` returns `Error: is.rtools(rtools) is not TRUE`

Comment: have fixed it. i actually have a diff problem from you. i get NULL for `scan_path_for_rtools` and `setup_rtools`. will be interested to know how you will solve this

Answer (score 0):

```
BINPREF ?= c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/
```

remove ? before =

Comment: Describe something about your answer will help others to easily catch your answer. refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer