# Why can't I install properly rtools40 x64 Widows?

Tags: r, rtools

I'm trying to install rtools40 according to the instructions at https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/. I've already set up the PATH, but when it comes for installing an R package from Source:

```
install.packages("jsonlite", type = "source")
```

It gives this error:

```
install.packages("jsonlite", type = "source")
probando la URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/jsonlite_1.7.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1057524 bytes (1.0 MB)
downloaded 1.0 MB

* installing *source* package 'jsonlite' ...
** package 'jsonlite' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs

*** arch - i386
"C:/rtools40/usr/bin/mingw32/bin/"gcc  -I"C:/R-40~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG -Iyajl/api       -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO   -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign -c base64.c -o base64.o
sh: C:/rtools40/usr/bin/mingw32/bin/gcc: No such file or directory
make: *** [C:/R-40~1.2/etc/i386/Makeconf:222: base64.o] Error 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'jsonlite'
* removing 'C:/R-4.0.2/library/jsonlite'
* restoring previous 'C:/R-4.0.2/library/jsonlite'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘jsonlite’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\Users\Mauro\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpqcxD9B\downloaded_packages’
```

I add the PATH routes that are currently active:

[image]

Comment: Does this happen with other packages you install from source? Could be an issue specific to that package.

Comment: Is there a reason you are building from source rather than just installing the CRAN binary version? The latter would be a lot easier. Does `file.exists("C:/rtools40/usr/bin/mingw32/bin/gcc")` return TRUE? What version of RStudio are you using? Are you sure you have a [32-bit Windows OS](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ie/office/determine-whether-your-computer-is-running-a-32-bit-version-or-64-bit-version-of-the-windows-operating-system-aac162a1-0cb3-46f2-888f-2f22897396ce). What does `Sys.getenv("R_ARCH")` return? Seeing "i386" makes me think 32 bit

Comment: Please show a screenshot/printout of your PATHs. Have you restarted R after installing Rtools?

Comment: @MrFlick I'm following the install instructions in the webpage, to be sure that everything works well.  `file.exists("C:/rtools40/usr/bin/mingw32/bin/gcc")` returns FALSE. The Rstudio version is 1.3.959. I checked and it is indeed 64 bits Windows. `Sys.getenv("R_ARCH")` returns "/x64".

Comment: @RomanLuštrik I did restart R, and when trying to find "make" by means of `Sys.which("make")` it returns **"C:\\rtools40\\usr\\bin\\make.exe"**.

Comment: @Phil I was also trying to install (update) Bioconductor and it gives this error: _C:/rtools40/usr/bin/mingw32/bin/gcc: No such file or directory make: *** [C:/R-40~1.2/etc/i386/Makeconf:222: dotsElt.o] Error 127 ERROR: compilation failed for package 'backports'_ (...) _Warning message: In install.packages(update[instlib == l, "Package"], l, repos = repos, : installation of package ‘backports’ had non-zero exit status_

Comment: Are you sure you doanloaded and ran the "rtools40-x86_64.exe" file? Did you edit any "Makeconf" or "Makevars" files? Does `file.exists("C:/rtools40/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe")` return true?

Comment: @MrFlick Yes, I downloaded rtools40-x86_64.exe. I haven't done modifications to the mentioned files. `file.exists("C:/rtools40/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe")` returns TRUE. 

What could be the problem? I just downloaded from bioconductor curatedOvarianData package and it runs well, actually that's what I need. But I still don't understand why there's this problem.

Comment: Does `file.exists("~/.R/Makevars")` return TRUE? It seems what you are experiencing may be related to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49895448/r-is-using-the-mingw-32-to-compile-packages-for-64-bit-architecture Have you had R installed on your machine before? What does `sessionInfo()$platform` return?

Comment: @MrFlick yes, I have R 4.0.1 installed among with Rstudio. `file.exists("~/.R/Makevars")` returns _FALSE_, and `sessionInfo()$platform` returns _"x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)"_

Comment: Looks to me like you're running R in 32 bit mode (`C:/R-40~1.2/etc/i386/Makeconf:222`). Run it in 64 bit mode and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a beginner at R, but I found this answer on another forum.

Choose a different CRAN repository, RStudios repository is a good choice (http://cran.rstudio.com/ ) or you could choose one that is geographically closer to you.

[image]

Disable secure download setting.

[image]

Check if your internet connection has traffic restrictions of some kind, like a firewall, proxy server, etc. This is usually the case when you are at work or school.

Answer (score 0):

1 No such file or directory, when you this mistake, you can just add "C:/rtools40/usr/bin/mingw32/bin/gcc" to your path(environmental variable

2 Also try to run Rstudio as administrator in a windows laptor