# How can I change the os in R from mingw32 to mingw64?

Tags: r

This is my R Studio details.

[image]

I would like to upgrade to the 64 bit version of mingw because I require more than 3 GB of memory.

Comment: x86_64 indicates that you are using a 64 bit version of R.  In fact, that's the only kind there is these days.  The "mingw32" name is just a name.

Comment: @jrcalabrese, have you guys found how to upgrade the mingw version ? I am runing dada2 on my data and at some points, it says that it couls not allocate memory, when I looked up this error I found out that it is related to mingw version. I tried to upgrade it folowing this instructions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49895448/r-is-using-the-mingw-32-to-compile-packages-for-64-bit-architecture 
but to no avail