# Problem with Rcmd.exe when installing packages

Tags: r, windows, gcc, package

I'm getting the following error when installing packages from github:

```
> devtools::install_github("pmartinezarbizu/pairwiseAdonis/pairwiseAdonis")
Downloading GitHub repo pmartinezarbizu/pairwiseAdonis@HEAD
Erro: Failed to install 'pairwiseAdonis' from GitHub:
  System command 'Rcmd.exe' failed, exit status: -1, stdout + stderr empty
```

With find_rtools, I get the following message (I was reading these posts, but couldn't solve my problem: https://github.com/r-lib/devtools/issues/2031 and [R CMD check not looking for gcc in Rtools directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47076620/r-cmd-check-not-looking-for-gcc-in-rtools-directory/47076968#47076968)):

```
> find_rtools(T)
Scanning R CMD config CC...
cc_path:  
'' does not exist
Scanning path...
ls: C:\Rtools\bin\ls.exe 
gcc_path: C:\Rtools\mingw_64\bin\gcc.exe 
VERSION.txt
Rtools version 3.5.0.4 
Version: 3.5 
Found compatible gcc on path
[1] TRUE
```

I'm using R v. 3.6.:

```
>     > session_info()
>     - Session info -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>      setting  value                       
>      version  R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
>      os       Windows 10 x64              
>      system   x86_64, mingw32             
>      ui       RStudio                     
>      language (EN)                        
>      collate  Portuguese_Brazil.1252      
>      ctype    Portuguese_Brazil.1252      
>      tz       America/Sao_Paulo           
>      date     2020-07-29
```

Comment: You need to add the R bin directory to your PATH.  It is something like `file.path(R.home(), "bin/x64")`.  (Use `list.files()` to make sure `Rcmd.exe` is there to confirm.)

Comment: What version of `devtools` are you running?

Comment: Devtools v. 2.3.1

I did try to include what I thought was necessary in the PATH. I think the problem is with my PATH variables, but I am afraid to make things worse by removing things.

These are the variables there (but there are more, e.g. python):

> Sys.getenv('PATH')
[1] "C:\\usr\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-3.6.3\\bin\\x64;
C:\\Rtools\\bin;
C:\\RBuildTools\\3.5\\bin;
C:\\Rtools\\bin;C:\\Rtools\\mingw_64\\bin;
C:\\Rtools\\mingw_64\\bin\\gcc;
C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-3.6.3\\bin\\x64;
C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-3.6.3\\bin\\x64\\Rcmd.exe;
C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-3.6.3\\bin

Comment: Working answers at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57777382/cannot-install-an-r-package-from-github

Answer (score 4):

If anyone's still having this problem, I was able to work around it using the `pak` package with the `pkg_install` function. It's possible this might not work for all package repositories, but it has worked for the ones I've needed it for.

Comment: Great solution! Straightforward, fully inside R, no need to do system changes. This worked for installing my packages.