# Cannot find Rtools to build package

Tags: r, rtools

I have R 3.5.0 and Rtools 3.5 installed on a Windows 10 machine. Running `devtools::find_rtools()` yields `TRUE` but when I try to check and build a package I'm working on, I get the error:

```
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/
```

Based on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33103203/rtools-is-not-being-detected-from-rstudio) I ran the following commands but get the same error:

```
Sys.setenv(PATH = paste("C:/Rtools/bin", Sys.getenv("PATH"), sep=";"))
Sys.setenv(BINPREF = "C:/Rtools/mingw_$(WIN)/bin/")
```

How can I get Rtools to be recognized to build a package?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out I needed to add `c:\Rtools\mingw_64\bin;` to my PATH as well.

Answer (score 0):

I hit this issue when running R-devel.  It turned out that R was looking for a newer version of Rtools: the R-devel build I was running was [updated](https://developer.r-project.org/blosxom.cgi/R-devel/NEWS/2023/01/02#n2023-01-02) to look by default for an [updated version](https://www.r-project.org/nosvn/winutf8/ucrt3/) of Rtools.