# Trouble installing Rtools

Tags: r, rstudio, rcpp, rtools

I'm having issues getting Rtools to function. I've searched around SO and other sites, and still can't get to the bottom of this.

I'm using R version 3.6.1, and trying to install Rtools 35. I'm using RStudio 1.0.143, but running the code in R console doesn't produce different results.

I've installed Rtools with Administrative Rights, in C:\Rtools
Rtools\bin, Rtools\mingw_32\bin, and Rtools\mingw_64\bin are all in PATH. The gcc compilers were installed in the mingw_32 and ming_64 binaries, and I copied the one from the mingw_32 folder and put it in Rtools\bin (as suggested by one post.

Running:

```
Sys.getenv('PATH')

> C:\\Users\\robin.ghertner\\Documents\\R\\R-3.6.1\\bin\\x64;C:\\oracle\\product\\11.2.0\\client_1\\BIN;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common
> Files\\Oracle\\Java\\javapath;C:\\Windows\\System32;C:\\Windows;C:\\Windows\\System32\\wbem;C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\;C:\\Windows\\System32\\OpenSSH\\;C:\\Program
> Files (x86)\\HID Global\\ActivClient\\;C:\\Program Files\\HID
> Global\\ActivClient\\;C:\\Program Files
> (x86)\\Sennheiser\\SoftphoneSDK\\;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common
> Files\\Roxio Shared\\DLLShared\\;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common
> Files\\Roxio Shared\\10.0\\DLLShared\\;C:\\Program Files
> (x86)\\CheckPoint\\Endpoint Security\\Endpoint Common\\bin;C:\\Program
> Files\\SASHome\\Secure\\ccme4;C:\\Program
> Files\\SASHome\\x86\\Secure\\ccme4;C:\\Users\\robin.ghertner\\Documents\\R\\R-3.6.1\\bin;C:\\Rtools\\bin;C:\\Rtools\\mingw_32\\bin;C:\\Rtools\\mingw_64\\bin;C:\\Users\\robin.ghertner\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps
```

Following [RStudio not finding RTools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51830648/rstudio-not-finding-rtools) ,

```
`Sys.which("ls.exe")`

> C:\\Rtools\\bin\\ls.exe

Sys.which("gcc.exe")

> "C:\\Rtools\\bin\\gcc.exe"
```

It looks like RTools is installed:

```
library(devtools)
find_rtools()

> [1] TRUE
```

However, doing a simple evaluation in Rcpp throws an error. Running:

```
library(Rcpp)
evalCpp("1+1",showOutput = T)

> C:/Users/ROBIN~1.GHE/DOCUME~1/R/R-36~1.1/bin/x64/R CMD SHLIB -o
> "sourceCpp_6.dll" "" "file319c51e36fba.cpp"  
> C:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/g++ 
> -I"C:/Users/ROBIN~1.GHE/DOCUME~1/R/R-36~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG   -I"C:/Users/robin.ghertner/Documents/R/R-3.6.1/library/Rcpp/include/"  -I"C:/Users/robin.ghertner/Documents/R/R-3.6.1/library/RcppEigen/include/"
> -I"C:/Users/robin.ghertner/Documents/R/R-3.6.1/library/RcppEigen/include/unsupported"
> -I"C:/Users/robin.ghertner/Documents/R/R-3.6.1/library/BH/include" -I"C:/Users/robin.ghertner/Documents/R/R-3.6.1/library/StanHeaders/include/src/"
> -I"C:/Users/robin.ghertner/Documents/R/R-3.6.1/library/StanHeaders/include/"
> -I"C:/Users/robin.ghertner/Documents/R/R-3.6.1/library/rstan/include" -DEIGEN_NO_DEBUG  -DBOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS -std=c++1y  -I"C:/Users/robin.ghertner/Documents/R/R-3.6.1/library/Rcpp/include" -I"C:/Users/robin.ghertner/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpSCAQxh/sourceCpp-x86_64-w64-mingw32-1.0.2"
> -march=native     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c file319c51e36fba.cpp -o file319c51e36fba.o
>       1 [main] make 14624 C:\Rtools\bin\make.exe: *** fatal error in forked process - fork: can't reserve memory for parent stack 0x1200000
> - 0x1400000, (child has 0xC00000 - 0xE00000), Win32 error 487
>     389 [main] make 14624 cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to make.exe.stackdump
>       0 [main] make 14852 fork: child -1 - forked process 14624 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0x100, errno 11 make: fork: Resource
> temporarily unavailable Error in sourceCpp(code = code, env = env,
> rebuild = rebuild, cacheDir = cacheDir,  :    Error 1 occurred
> building shared library.
```

I've restarted my computer, and tried reinstalling Rtools a couple of times. I'm at a loss of what to try next.

Comment: Are you on a 32 bit or 64 bit machine? You should probably only include the one on your path that's relevant for your machine architecture. This might help you determine which you have: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/827218/how-to-determine-whether-a-computer-is-running-a-32-bit-version-or-64

Comment: The Eigen/BH/Stan/... includes are *not* added by Rcpp when you do `evalCpp()` -- which is why that is a good litmus test.  Maybe your `~/.R/Makevars` is borked?

Comment: Also make sure your Rtools PATH setting is at the front.  Else a wrong tool may get picked up.  I used to write myself batch files that just pre-pended the R paths when I needed them.

Answer (score 0):

1. you need to check your folder name(C:/Rtools40/usr/bin)
2. you need to check which bit you used. (32bit or 64bit)
3. https://github.com/r-windows/docs/blob/master/rtools40.md#readme
   --> you should open pacman and follow pacman command
4. If you still have error then you need to check Bioconductor version so that you can figure it out..maybe

```html
 if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
    install.packages("BiocManager")
BiocManager::install(version = "3.11")
```