# install.packages throwing Rtools warning after R 3.6 update

Tags: r

I recently updated R to 3.6 and started installing my commonly used packages. Each time I use the "install.packages()" command it throws the following error:

```
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:
```

It looks like the packages install and function correctly, but I've not experienced this behavior before. I've been using R intermittently for 3 years. Thanks for your help.

Comment: What package are you trying to install? Did you choose an option to build from source? What operating system are you on?

Comment: Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50938412/rstudio-cannot-find-rtools-to-build-package

Comment: Thanks for your input. I installed Rtools and stopped getting the errors, though it does ask me occasionally if I want to build some new packages from source.