# RTools Version 3.5 not compatible with R 3.5 when running inside R Studio- Has anyone experienced this issue?

Tags: r, rtools

I tried this command : `devtools::find_rtools()`

Error Message I receive on R Studio:

> WARNING: Rtools 3.5 found on the path at C:/RBUILD~1/3.5 is not compatible with R 3.5.1.
>
> Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools from http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/, remove the incompatible version from your PATH.
>
> Currently the latest version of RTools available is RTools 3.5 (Currently installed) https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rtools is not being detected from RStudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33103203/rtools-is-not-being-detected-from-rstudio)

Comment: Rtools 3.5 is being detected and is detected as incompatible with R 3.5.1. Try this: https://community.rstudio.com/t/error-dependency-transformr-is-not-available-for-package-gganimate/11134/4

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on my laptop, but not on my desktop. After some checking, I realized that I have two different devtools versions on the two machines, everything else is the same. On my desktop, I have devtools version 2.0.1, while on my laptop it was a much earlier version (I can't remember which now). After updating the devtools package on my laptop, it worked. I've read somewhere about issues with earlier versions of devtools so I'm pretty sure this is the reason.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21385532)

Comment: I've elaborated the answer a little bit more. I hope it is sufficientn ow.

Comment: I don't understand how this does not answer the question. I experienced the exact same problem and found a way to fix it.

Comment: @Drumy your answer is flagged as low quality post and therefore people are paying close attention to it because it's in the review queue. I think your answer is OK for this particular question, but I guess it is a matter of how many people vote in one or the other direction