# R: "make" not found when installing a R-package from local tar.gz

Tags: r, installation, package, cran

The R Package `ConvCalendar` is not on Cran repository anymore (see [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ConvCalendar/index.html)).
However, because I have intensively used this package for previous projects, it would be nice to have it installed on my machine, even an older version would suffice.

(Windows 10 environment)

In the link above it is possible to download older versions of `ConvCalendar` from the archive. I thus did it, and tried installing it by running (having `devtools` also installed and loaded):

```
install.packages("ConvCalendar_1.2.tar.gz", repos=NULL, type="source")
```

However, I get the following error message:

```
> install.packages("ConvCalendar_1.0.tar.gz", repos=NULL, type="source")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/myname/Documents/R/win-library/3.5’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
* installing *source* package 'ConvCalendar' ...
** libs

*** arch - i386
Warning in system(cmd) : 'make' not found
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'ConvCalendar'
* removing 'C:/Users/myname/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/ConvCalendar'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘ConvCalendar_1.2.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Looking for a solution to this problem.

Comment: Used OS? If it's ubuntu/debian, try `sudo apt-get install make` from shell. If it's windows, it's likely that you have to build the Rtools. See here: https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/

Comment: Windows 10. I write this is the main question

Comment: See the edit to the first comment. You likely need Rtools.

Comment: Thanks, that worked!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

what do you need is to update the Rtool. Here is the [link](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/). I had the same issue before.Once you update it, it will work.

Comment: On Windows also note that the directory where make.exe is installed is accessible and in the path

Comment: This worked for me, and then I had to set the path - thanks all!

Answer (score 5):

Reinstall Rtools, Please check the below link to figure out the right version of Rtools.

https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/history.html

Answer (score 2):

`'make' not found` is a pretty clear cut message on what's the issue, and as noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62469777/rtools-not-found-by-r-when-installing-packages-from-cran) and [elsewhere](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2019-September/463992.html) it is caused by Rterm not knowing where to find it (unlike other tools like RStudio, base R is completely clueless about the Windows registry value where the Rtools path gets set by default).

Up to Rtools 3.5 this could be neatly avoided with a checkbox in the installer (which took care of adding the right directory to PATH), but newer versions dropped it. Presumably to focus on the RTOOLS_HOME variable (which is far more independent and resilient to whatever else you may have installed on your system), if just so it wasn't that until [R 4.2](https://github.com/wch/r-source/commit/cf0b90ee825773bcf2ff94fad1b67c8f104a114d) nothing really cared for it in the code.

On top of that, it's only since Rtools 4.0 (maybe because they updated the old MSYS2/Cygwin environment, or maybe it was something in the accompanying [R 4.0](https://bugs.r-project.org/show_bug.cgi?id=17709)?) that you can use long filenames with spaces to point to the folder containing *make*. Also, hopefully you haven't been manually setting [BINPREF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33103203/rtools-is-not-being-detected-from-rstudio) anywhere.

**TL;DR**: just add something like "C:\rtools40\usr\bin" (or whatever you have) to your PATH.

Answer (score 2):

Building on @mirh's answer.

I had installed Rtools 4.0 in the in "C:\rtools" on windows and had the "'make' not found" issue (I also had a warning that RTools was not found). I could not change the PATH through the traditional route though because I was missing admin rights. The following helped:

Add to your .RProfile the line:

```
Sys.setenv(PATH = paste0(Sys.getenv("PATH"), ";C:\\rtools40\\usr\\bin"))
```

This will change the path from within R for the current session. You might have to alter it if you have a different version of RTools or a different installation directory.

After this I can install from source and I don't get the RTools warning anymore.