# Which version of R studio is compatible with Windows 7 32 bit?

Tags: r, windows, 32bit-64bit

I am trying to search for a version of R studio that can be run on 32 bit Windows but I am unable to find one. Can someone please help? It would be really helpful if you drop link of website as well.

Comment: Try this one: http://download1.rstudio.org/RStudio-1.1.463.exe

Comment: But really, everyone has already moved to 64bit

Comment: This question is about x32, but for x64 same end of life currently occurs and here https://community.rstudio.com/t/r-studio-for-windows-7-will-not-run-entry-point-not-found/169207 it was correctly noticed that 2023.03.2 still works on W7 x64.

Answer (score 0):

The last official stable version was [1.1.463](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/older-versions/#rstudio-desktop-11463), as also mentioned in the comments.

The removal of Windows 32-bit support only happened [mid-way](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/pull/2993) through the 1.2 development cycle though. And so if you feel daring (or I don't know what other feature you might want) you can try [build 736](https://s3.amazonaws.com/rstudio-ide-build/desktop/windows/RStudio-1.2.736.exe) too.

A couple of notes: if you use anything that relies on pandoc, please manually [upgrade](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/releases/tag/2.9.2.1) its executable in the RStudio installation folder (even because it's not like the built-in one will work anyway).

Also, while technically the last supported 32-bit R version is [4.1.3](https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/base/old/4.1.3/), some features may not be available in the old RStudio release (or if not any I know the graphics engine version is too new to mix seamlessly with the IDE). Therefore you could be interested to [4.0.5](https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/base/old/4.0.5/) instead.

Last but not least, I'd recommend to install [Rtools](https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/) ([caveat emptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53279685/r-make-not-found-when-installing-a-r-package-from-local-tar-gz)), since a number of packages are going to give a far better time if compiled from source.