# Package installation issue with R version 3.6.0

Tags: r, windows, htmltools

I have R 3.6.0 (and I'm currently obliged to use this version of R) and I'm facing the following problem. My goal is to install the 'shiny' package.
I run

```
install.packages("shiny",checkBuilt=TRUE, ask=FALSE)
```

and this triggers the following error:

```
** package 'bslib' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  namespace 'htmltools' 0.5.1.1 is being loaded, but >= 0.5.2 is required
Calls: <Anonymous> ... withCallingHandlers -> loadNamespace -> namespaceImport -> loadNamespace
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'bslib'
* removing 'C:/bin/R-3.6.0/library/bslib'
```

My understanding is that it needs to install package 'bslib' but in order to do so, I need to upgrade my 'htmltools' package to 0.5.2.
Such version since to be available only as source, hence I run the following:

```
install.packages("htmltools", type='source')
```

This gives me the following error message:

```
* installing *source* package 'htmltools' ...
** package 'htmltools' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs

*** arch - i386
Warning in system(cmd) : 'make' not found
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'htmltools'
* removing 'C:/bin/R-3.6.0/library/htmltools'
* restoring previous 'C:/bin/R-3.6.0/library/htmltools'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘htmltools’ had non-zero exit status
```

This looks like I have to install the package 'make'.
If I run the following:

```
install.packages("make")
```

I get the error message:

```
package ‘make’ is not available (for R version 3.6.0)
```

At this point, I'm quite desperate.
What else shall I do? Thank you

Comment: `make` is a program, not an R package. You need to install Rtools for it to work. I am assuming you are using Windows.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53279685/r-make-not-found-when-installing-a-r-package-from-local-tar-gz

Comment: @hyena yes, I'm using Windows. Would you have any recommendation of how to install make compatible with my version of R?

Comment: @Angelo Just install the corresponding version of Rtools on your pc. Google it or use the link above by @ Joe Erinjeri

Comment: Here, use this link to pick the correct version. https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/history.html

Comment: that works, thank you