# Installation of package '.../audio.whisper_0.2.1.tar.gz' has a non-zero exit status

Tags: r, whisper

Good afternoon everyone!

I am trying to install [audio.whisper](https://github.com/bnosac/audio.whisper#readme) package in R.
I have done everything according to the instructions:

```
remotes::install_github("bnosac/audio.whisper", ref = "0.2.1")
```

I got an error, because remotes library was not installed, so I installed it.
When running `remotes::install_github("bnosac/audio.whisper", ref = "0.2.1")` I get an error: *Installation of package '.../audio.whisper_0.2.1.tar.gz' has non-zero exit status*:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFMVr.png)

Next, I follow the recommendation and install Rtools and the pkgbuild library:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGf5p.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RIhu.png)
Even if on the notification that there are newer versions of packages, I choose to update everything - the result is the same:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0YPz.png)

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong, or if I'm doing everything right, what's missing and what needs to be installed?
My goal is to transcribe audio into text.

UPDATE: Following the advice I restarted RStudio after installing Rtools - it worked, audio.whisper was installed. But even here it did not do without problems - it seems to be installed, but it refuses to load the model:

```
> remotes::install_github("bnosac/audio.whisper", ref = "0.2.1")
Skipping install of 'audio.whisper' from a github remote, the SHA1 (ee508e82) has not changed since last install.
  Use `force = TRUE` to force installation
> require(audio.whisper)
Загрузка требуемого пакета: audio.whisper
> help(package = "audio.whisper")
> library(audio.whisper)
> model <- whisper("large")
trying URL 'https://huggingface.co/datasets/ggerganov/whisper.cpp/resolve/main/ggml-large.bin'
Something went wrong
Error in utils::download.file(url = url, destfile = to, mode = "wb") : 
  cannot open URL 'https://huggingface.co/datasets/ggerganov/whisper.cpp/resolve/main/ggml-large.bin'

whisper_init_from_file: loading model from 'E:/Документы/ggml-large.bin'
whisper_init_from_file: failed to open 'E:/Документы/ggml-large.bin'
>
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: It doesn't look like you installed RTools https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/. You need to do that outside of R. Make sure to use a version that matches the R version you are running. Restart R after you install RTools to make sure it can find the new tools. You can run `pkgbuild::find_rtools()` to make sure the program is installed correctly. In the future, please [do not post code or errors in images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/2372064) -- it makes it harder for other to search for similar problems.

Comment: @MrFlick, do you have good past-questions for Rtools? (I don't.) It seems that that should be a FAQ (with solid, canonical answers) for dupe-questions.

Comment: @r2evans Not sure I have a great one. This one seems to match the "make not found" error that was shown in the screen shots: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53279685/r-make-not-found-when-installing-a-r-package-from-local-tar-gz

Comment: @MrFlick, I have that one too, was hoping for something a little better :-). Thanks!

Comment: @MrFlick Yes, I installed RTools outside of RStudio. About the code on the screenshots - I took note of it, I'll fix it!

Comment: It would be great if someone asked an intended  canonical dupe for RTools... none of the ones I can find are very comprehensive.

Comment: @prolabrus I'd recommend updating your packages. Your 3rd screenshot says "It is recommended to update packages" and asked you which to update. You selected `3: None` Instead, try selecting `1: All`.

Comment: @Gregor Thomas, Yes, that's what I did, I've attached a screenshot too.

Comment: What if you try `model <- whisper("large", repos="ggerganov")`

Comment: @MrFlick - Same thing:
```
library(audio.whisper)
model <- whisper("large", repos="ggerganov")
trying URL 'https://ggml.ggerganov.com/ggml-model-whisper-large.bin'
Something went wrong
Error in utils::download.file(url = url, destfile = to, mode = "wb") : 
  cannot open URL 'https://ggml.ggerganov.com/ggml-model-whisper-large.bin'

whisper_init_from_file: loading model from 'E:/Документы/ggml-model-whisper-large.bin'
whisper_init_from_file: failed to open 'E:/Документы/ggml-model-whisper-large.bin'
```

Comment: It looks like all the URLs that are hard coded in the package for the model downloads are incorrect. Maybe try filing an issue with the package author to update to the correct URLs: https://github.com/bnosac/audio.whisper/issues