# Rcatrogram package : how to parameter Makevars.win file?

Tags: c, r, windows, gcc

I am trying to build a cartogram and followed the process described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31613119/installing-rcartogram-packages-error-message)
.

At the last step when I want to install the package I have the following error:

> ***
>       arch - i386  
>  
>       gcc -m32 -shared -s -static-libgcc -o Rcartogram.dll tmp.def Rcart.o cart.o -LC:/msys/fftwtest/x64 -LC:/msys/fftwtest/i386 -lfftw3-3 -lm -Ld:/RCompile/r-compiling/local/local320/lib/i386 -Ld:/RCompile/r-compiling/local/local320/lib -LC:/dev/R-PORT~1/App/R-PORT~1/bin/i386 -lR
>   C:/msys/fftwtest/x64/libfftw3-3.dll: file not recognized: File format not recognized
>   collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status 
>   no DLL was created

I tried to invert the path to load the library in the Makevars.win file ie `PKG_LIBS=-L"C:/msys/fftwtest/i386" -L"C:/msys/fftwtest/x64"`. Then the 32bit version is correctly installed but I got the following message:

> ***arch - x64
>  
>   gcc -m64 -I"C:/dev/R-PORT~1/App/R-PORT~1/include" -DNDEBUG -I"C:/msys  /fftwtest/x64"   -DNOPROGRESS     -I"d:/RCompile/r-compiling/local/local320/include"     -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=core2 -c Rcart.c -o Rcart.o
>   Rcart.c:1:0: sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in

It seems that the second option -L in the Makevars.win is not taken into account each time.
Does someone have an idea on how to solve this?
 I am working on a windows machine.
Here are my session info:

```
R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=French_France.1252  LC_CTYPE=French_France.1252 >LC_MONETARY=French_France.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C               
[5] LC_TIME=French_France.1252

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
[1] devtools_1.9.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.2.1   memoise_0.2.1 git2r_0.11.0  digest_0.6.8
```