# Mapping World Countries function of a factor

Tags: r, visualization, geospatial

I would like to create maps of the world where the size of the countries would be a function of a given factor such as GDP, size of population, CO2 emission etc..As an illustration the surface for the US would be the biggest  if I used GDP as the size factor and China the biggest if I used population size. Does anyone knows of a package that could handle this ? There are quite a few geo spatial packages but I have not found one with which you can affect the size of a country on the map relative to the rest of the world....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9319597/cartogram-choropleth-map-in-r

Comment: Thank you so much this is exactely what I was after