# create a map with the adapted size of states

Tags: r, ggplot2, shapefile, geo, matplotlib-basemap

Hi visualization lovers,

I am trying to create a color map plot,like this one: [image: like this one]
(source: https://github.com/hrbrmstr/albersusa)

**BUT**  i want  this maps to be biased so that the areas of the states to be proportional to the value I provide (in particular,I use GPD value).
 What i mean is that  I want some states to look bigger, some smaller that they are in reality **but reminding the real USA map as much as possible.** 
No problems with the states moving or shape destroying.

Any ideas? Any ready solutions?
Currently I use R and albersusa package because it is something I am familiar with. Open to change!
My current code for the plot is:

```
           gmap<-
           ggplot() +
           geom_map(data = counties@data, map = cmap,
                     aes(fill =atan(y/x),alpha=x+y, map_id = name),
                     color = "gray50") +
            geom_map(data = smap, map = smap,
                     aes(x = long, y = lat, map_id = id),
                     color = "black", size = .5, fill = NA) +
            theme_map(base_size = 12) +
            theme(plot.title=element_text(size = 16, face="bold",margin=margin(b=10))) +
            theme(plot.subtitle=element_text(size = 14, margin=margin(b=-20))) +
            theme(plot.caption=element_text(size = 9, margin=margin(t=-15),hjust=0)) +
scale_fill_viridis()+guides(alpha=F,fill=F)
```

Comment: You could try making a cartogram? See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9319597/cartogram-choropleth-map-in-r).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a very ugly first try to get you started, using the outlines from the `maps` package and some data manipulation from `dplyr`.

```
library(maps)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

# Generate the base outlines
mapbase <- map_data("state.vbm")    

# Load the centroids
data(state.vbm.center)

# Coerce the list to a dataframe, then add in state names
# Then generate some random value (or your variable of interest, like population)
# Then rescale that value to the range 0.25 to 0.95

df <- state.vbm.center %>% as.data.frame() %>% 
  mutate(region = unique(mapbase$region),
         somevalue = rnorm(50),
         scaling = scales::rescale(somevalue, to = c(0.25, 0.95)))
df 

# Join your centers and data to the full state outlines
df2 <- df %>% 
  full_join(mapbase) 
df2

# Within each state, scale the long and lat points to be closer
#   to the centroid by the scaling factor

df3 <- df2 %>% 
  group_by(region) %>% 
  mutate(longscale = scaling*(long - x) + x,
         latscale = scaling*(lat - y) + y) 
df3
```

---

```
# Plot both the outlines for reference and the rescaled polygons

  ggplot(df3, aes(long, lat, group = region, fill = somevalue)) + 
  geom_path() +
  geom_polygon(aes(longscale, latscale)) +
  coord_fixed() + 
  theme_void() + 
  scale_fill_viridis()
```

[image]

These outlines aren't the best, and the centroid positions they shrink toward cause the polygons to sometimes overlap the original state outline. But it's a start; you can find better shapes for US states and various centroid algorithms.